# how to orient a polymer paper button at the bottom of the screen

Tags: web, web-applications, polymer, web-component

I am working on a polymer app. I need to place a button which will always at the bottom of the screen. how can I achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just make its position absolute in the main document and set its bottom and right margins. Making the position absolute removes the element from the standard flow and makes the other elements ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to place the button(s) at right bottom of the page use the following class:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    .bottom-right {
        position: fixed;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;  
    }
</style>
```

The following is an example of two buttons placed at bottom right of the page. I placed the two buttons within a paper-material element to move both buttons together.

```
<paper-material elevation="0" class="bottom-right">
    <paper-button raised>
        <iron-icon icon="icons:save"></iron-icon>Save
    </paper-button>
    <paper-button raised>
        <iron-icon icon="icons:cancel"></iron-icon>Cancel
    </paper-button>
</paper-material>
```

Quite often the buttons are placed within a paper-dialog, in that case one desires to place buttons at bottom right of the dialog. In order to move buttons relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed), change position to absolute as in the following snippet.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;  
    }
</style>
```